# How can I make my mouse auto-click every 5 seconds?

Tags: mouse

I want to click on something for hours. How can I make a script or use an application so the mouse will auto-click every 5 seconds or less?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Edit: `xdotool click --delay 5000 --repeat 200 1`

For 200 clicks with mouse

---

Open terminal, install xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Also, open the window you want to click side by side with terminal. Select terminal (as active window) and **move the mouse over the point where you want to click**. In terminal type (try not to move the mouse)

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

You will need the x:**XXX** and y:**YYY** (bottom). You can move the mouse from here, but let windows stay where they are.
Type

```
gedit script
```

Paste the following on gedit (change the XXX and YYY for the numbers you got before)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
  xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1 &
  sleep 5
done
```

Save and close it. Then

```
chmod +x script
```

To execute it,

```
./script
```

To get less, simply change the **5** after sleep to less.

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=925217

Comment: `while sleep 5; do ...`

Comment: The 1 in `click 1` means left mouse button. From the manpage: "Left mouse is 1, middle is 2, right is 3, wheel up is 4, wheel down is 5."

Comment: `xdotool click --delay 5000 --repeat 100000 1` (assuming the mouse is left where it needs to click). And no need for a script for more complicated cases... while loops work on the command line... (@Olathe's method is much better as well...). `while sleep 5; do xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1; done`

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Please make your comment an answer!

Comment: (That comment is now an answer)

Answer (score 18):

I went to this [page](https://launchpad.net/~c-korn/+archive/ppa/+packages) and downloaded the `xautoclick_0.20-1~ppa1_amd64.deb (14.3 KiB)` 
and it works great :D

[image]

Thanks to Kat Amsterdam for finding xautoclick

Comment: It is dangerous to just download a single file and install it. In order to receive security updates for the package and new features it is reccomended to install the ppa:::

apt-add-repository ppa:c-korn/ppa

Comment: This package has now been removed; see answer by @KatAmsterdam.  Any ideas where to get it without being root?

Comment: here is download page    .... https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/ubuntu/extra/+build/2179450

Answer (score 8):

With xdotool installed: (`apt-get install xdotool` (As root or with `sudo`))

This will click in the current mouse position every 5 seconds for 100000 times (That is somewhere between 5 and 6 days...)

```bsh
xdotool click --delay 5000 --repeat 100000 1 # (assuming the mouse is left where it needs to click).
```

To click in a specific place: (In a command-line friendly version, for a script you probably want better formatting)

```bsh
while sleep 5; do xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 1; done
```

(`--repeat` can be used on the click here as well, but that won't repeat the move...)

Comment: Nice solution !!!

Comment: You can even pass the cursor location as variables: eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell);
while sleep 5; do xdotool mousemove $X $Y click 1; done

Comment: also just for fun `printf 'click --delay 5000 1\n' | xargs yes | xdotool -`

Answer (score 6):

In **Lucid 10.04 LTS**

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center
2. In the search box, type in autoclick
3. Download xautoclick

   For **Precise 12.04LTS** the package has been removed from the Ubuntu Repositories and is only available via GetDeb.

   [xautoclick instructions for install in precise](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps?dist=precise)

   or via Christoph Korn's PPA (who is a member of GetDeb):

   `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:c-korn/ppa`
4. Download xautoclick via the software center
   **(or if you are handy with the terminal)**

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install xautoclick`
5. Read the instructions on xautoclick `man xautoclick`
6. Under Programs, Accesories choose xautoclick
7. Change the Interval to 5000 (the value is milliseconds)
8. Click Start
9. Move the mouse over what you would like to click
10. Enjoy!

    [image: xautoclick]

To enable the GetDeb repositories:

```bsh
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu precise-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
```

Comment: none of those were in the software-center and i found this one http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kautoclick/ but after installing it i get this error when trying to open it: kautoclick: error while loading shared libraries: libkdeui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

For even more automation you can use [sikuli](http://sikuli.org/).

Sikuli has integrated tool that allows you to very simply write any form of interaction (mouse clicking or keyboard) by visual processing where is what on screen.

You simply select where you want your click to occur by visually selecting screen part and off it goes. Automation logic is written in python, but even if you don't have any clue about python you can easily figure it out, because tool provides you with everything right away!

You can simply install it with `sudo apt-get install sikuli-ide`.