# Is there a command to scroll?

Tags: command-line, mouse-scroll, scrolling, execute-command

Other than using `xdotool` is there a way to scroll down by a set amount using a command. In other words, what is the scrolling command?

I'm not looking for a keyboard shortcut, I want a command for scrolling by say 10px in the currently focussed window. I also don't want `xdotool` because I need the "deeper command", what is "executed" when the wheel is rolled.

Comment: Next time tell us first what you NOT want?

Comment: @Korkel, I did say without `xdotool`

Comment: Your last edit...

Comment: `xdotool` [literally provides and executes a wheel scroll event](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162351/167115), not a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xdotool` lets you send keyboard keys too so all the standard stuff like:

```
xdotool key Page_Down
xdotool key Down Down Down  # presses down three times with a 12ms delay
xdotool key --delay 2 Down Down Down  # as above but 2ms
```

---

With respect to the "deeper command", there's no one such thing. A window is sent an event (like a mousewheel) and *it* (the program or —more commonly— its toolkit) decides how to interpret that.

The scrolling isn't directly controllable (unless you're using an application or framework that provides an interface for doing just that). [I've explained this a little bit more in your last question](https://askubuntu.com/a/474559/449).

Comment: I don't want to use xdotool, I want a "deeper" command, not xdotool, which essentially emulates the press.

Comment: @Tim Yeah I've added a bit for that. With the exception of really weird circumstances that I've never experienced, I don't think you can do this.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly what you asked for, because the OP asked for "10px" scrolling, but since it also asked for "what is executed when the wheel is rolled".  In Linux, when the wheel is rolled, it's up to the application to interpret it, but you can still simulate wheel rolling.

Wheel rolling up and down are typically mapped as [mouse button 4 and 5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) respectively.  The following command will simulate scrolling up

```
xdotool click 4
```

and the following command will simulate scrolling down

```
xdotool click 5
```

Use custom shortcuts or scripts to bind your input events to this command to simulate a wheel roll.

Comment: `while true; do xdotool click 5; sleep 0.1; done` will scroll down until you kill the command with CTRL+C

Answer (score 0):

- Install `xdotool`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Get mouse pointer location:

  ```
  xdotool getmouselocation
  ```
- Scroll using click 4 & 5 (change XXX and YYY from above command):

  ```
  xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 4

  xdotool mousemove XXX YYY click 5
  ```

**Source**: https://askubuntu.com/a/329009/536195

Answer (score -1):

**Scroll backwards:**

```
Shift + Page Up
```

**Scroll Forwards:**

```
Shift + Page Down
```

Comment: No, not a keyboard shortcut, a command for scrolling by say 10px

Comment: Chek `tools-options-advanced-use autoscroll`?

Comment: Is this the command, or a place to navigate to?

Comment: Place navigate to, on mobile now. :$

Comment: I'm a bit confused, could you expand please?